# Add service to IServiceCollection NOT in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, .net-5, dependency-management

I have Startup and IHosterService in witch I want to add a service to IServiceCollection. Problem is, after I add my service to IServiceCollection I can't get it from IServiceProvider

I tried to add my service to IServiceColection in IHostedService, but after I added my service I can't get it from IServiceProvider. Have I any chance to add service in IHostedService and after in get new service from IServiceProvider?

Startup

```
public class Startup {
... 
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddHostedService<InitHostedService>();
        //without this line I can't resolve IServiceCollection in InitHostedService
        services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection>(services);
}
```

InitHostedService

```
public class InitHostedService : IHostedService {
    private readonly IServiceCollection _services;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public InitHostedService(IServiceCollection services, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        _services = services;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { 
        var serviceUri = // get actual uri for my service

        if (serviceUri != null) {
            // add service with uri to IServiceCollaction
            _services.AddServiceClient<IIdMapperServiceClient, IdMapperServiceClient>(serviceUri); 
            // can't get here my added service
            var a = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIdMapperServiceClient>(); 
    }
...
}
```

AddServiceClient extension

```
    public static void AddServiceClient<TServiceContract, TImplementation>(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Uri serviceUri)
        where TServiceContract : class
        where TImplementation : class, TServiceContract {
        services.AddHttpClient<TServiceContract, TImplementation>((sp, client) => { client.BaseAddress = serviceUri; });
    }
```

Comment: We would need to see the code where you try to register the type and where you try to resolve the object (get the actual object).

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why don't you call `AddServiceClient` in your `ConfigureServices` method? . Hosted services are long running background jobs, not a way to register or initialize other services. Your hosted service should only except an `IIdMapperServiceClient` in its constructor. It's up to the runtime to provide one

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the service URL from the configuration? You can do that in your `AddHttpClient`. The `IServiceProvider` parameter can be used to retrieve an `IConfiguration` instance or any other registered configuration object.

Comment: Finally, .NET 5 reached End Of Life 7 months ago. .NET 5 was a single-year-support "current" version. It's completely unsupported now. The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6. It's a Long-Term-Support version, supported until 2024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. `IServiceProvider` is built from `IServiceCollection` during startup process. When this happens - `IServiceProvider` *copies* services from `IServiceCollection`. So when your hosted service starts - `IServiceProvider` has already been built with services that you added during startup. Adding more services to `IServiceCollection` after that will have no effect, because `IServiceProvider` is "detached" from this collection already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to do something like that.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtension
{

    public static  IServiceCollection RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection servicesCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        servicesCollection.AddControllers();
        servicesCollection.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        servicesCollection.AppServices();
        servicesCollection.AddIdentity();
        servicesCollection.AddSwagger();
        servicesCollection.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
        servicesCollection.AddDatabase(configuration);
        
        var appSettings = servicesCollection.GetApplicationSettings(configuration);
        servicesCollection.AddJwtTokenAtuhentication(appSettings);

        return servicesCollection;
    }
```

Hope it helps